# Torque for seesaw rotation

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, equilibrium

Suppose there is a mechanical seesaw which makes the up/down seesaw movement so that even one kid can play seesaw. Now the motor shaft is fit at the axis of rotation or center of seesaw basically where a usual seesaw fulcrum or pivot is.

Scenario 1: One kid is place on one end of seesaw 
Scenario 2: Two kids placed on ends of seesaw

According to equations of torque, it does seem that the torque required to move two kids will be less than one kid but intuitively I am not comfortable with that. In that case basically, instead of kids, you can have very high point masses placed on the end of the seesaw and relatively very low torque motor still it should be able to create the movement because most of the torque is balanced by both the masses.

Can anyone confirm whether what I am saying can really happen ?

Comment: Ask which concepts related to the problem you couldn't understand and not the question. Stack exchange is not a Homework help site like other sites. By understanding the concept you will able to solve lots of problems

Comment: According to equations of torque it does seems that the torque required to move two kids will be less than with one kid in both the questions but intuitively I am not comfortable with that. In that case basically instead of kids you can have very hugh masses placed on extreme end of the seesaw and relatively very low torque motor still it should be able to create the movement because most of the torque is balanced by both the masses. I am not a Mechanical Engineer so my mechanics is not strong. Hence I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the torque to hold the seesaw in position against gravity is smaller when there are two kids on opposites sides than when there is only one kid. In fact, in the case of two equal-mass kids, it takes zero torque for the seesaw to remain still. Any small, non-zero torque will then cause the seesaw to move. However, the acceleration of the seesaw depends on the amount of torque from the motor. More massive kids require a larger motor to get the same acceleration.

This is equivalent to a pair of identical masses hanging over a pulley. Sure, any non-zero force on one block will start them moving, regardless of their mass, because gravity is balanced by the other block. However, if a certain acceleration is required, more massive blocks will require more force to achieve that acceleration.

As an example of a balanced seesaw on a large scale, the [Falkirk Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkirk_Wheel) can lift ships weighing up to 250 tons up to an elevated canal 24 meters up using 30-hp motors. This is possible because the weight of the water and boats on one side of the wheel is kept balanced by the water and boats on the other side, nearly negating the effect of gravity. High speed isn't desired here, so a small motor is all that is needed.